# How to set width and height of cell item in GridView programmatically in Android

Tags: android, arrays, gridview, items

I am trying to set a dynamic width and height of my GridView's items, this is my code:

```
 class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
            private Context context;
            private GridAdapter(Context context, List<ParseObject> objects) {
                super();
                this.context = context;
            }

            // CONFIGURE CELL
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View cell, ViewGroup parent) {
                if (cell == null) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    cell = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell_post_search, null);
                }

                //-----------------------------------------------
                // MARK - INITIALIZE VIEWS
                //-----------------------------------------------
                ImageView postImg = cell.findViewById(R.id.cpsPostImg);
                ImageView videoicon = cell.findViewById(R.id.cpsVideoIcon);

            ...

            return cell;
            }
                @Override public int getCount() { return postsArray.size(); }
                @Override public Object getItem(int position) { return postsArray.get(position); }
                @Override public long getItemId(int position) { return position; }
        }

        // Set Adapter
        postsGridView.setAdapter(new GridAdapter(ctx, postsArray));

        // Set number of Columns accordingly to the device used
        float scalefactor = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * screenW/3; // LET'S PRETEND MY screenW = 720, this value whoudl, be 240, which is the width i need for my cell

        int number = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        int columns = (int) ((float) number / scalefactor);
        postsGridView.setNumColumns(columns);
        Log.i(Configurations.TAG, "SCALE FACTOR: " + scalefactor);
```

And here's my custom **cell_post_search.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/cpsCellLayout"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cpsPostImg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="#c1c1c1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cpsVideoIcon"
            android:layout_width="44dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/cpsPostImg"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/play_butt"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cpsWhiteFrame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/white_frame"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I get 480.0 as scale factor in my Logcat, which is not the right size I need (in my case it should be 240). Anyway, I've also tried to do this:

```
int columns = (int) ((float) number / (scalefactor/2));
```

So the `scalefactor` = 240, but it doesn't matter, because I need my cell's item to be square size, so basically: **WIDTH = screenWidth/3**, **HEIGHT = screenWidth/3**.

It doesn't work properly, my GridView shows 3 columns but cells get stretched in width - height looks fine - as shown here:

[image: Stretched width for cells]

Is there a way to edit my code and make cells size correctly, as square images, 3 columns, based on the device size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
 class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;
        private GridAdapter(Context context, List<ParseObject> objects) {
            super();
            this.context = context;
        }

        // CONFIGURE CELL
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View cell, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (cell == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                cell = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell_post_search, null);
            }

            //-----------------------------------------------
            // MARK - INITIALIZE VIEWS
            //-----------------------------------------------
            ImageView postImg = cell.findViewById(R.id.cpsPostImg);
            ImageView videoicon = cell.findViewById(R.id.cpsVideoIcon);

            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            ((Activity) mContext).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
            int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
            postImg.getLayoutParams().height = width / 3;

        ...

        return cell;
        }
            @Override public int getCount() { return postsArray.size(); }
            @Override public Object getItem(int position) { return postsArray.get(position); }
            @Override public long getItemId(int position) { return position; }
    }
```

Also, in your XML layout, add `android:numColumns="3"`:

```
<GridView
            android:id="@+id/upPostsGridView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:numColumns="3"/>
```

Comment: I did, unfortunately, this is what I get: https://s6.postimg.cc/4j5t52v1t/Screenshot_2018-07-11-11-07-08.png - I've removed the code below // Set number of Columns accordingly to the device used

Comment: PS: I've edited your answer, that's how I've fixed the issue, anyway thanks so much for your answer!